# Can I keep my classes EF-Migrations in a testing project?

Tags: ef-code-first, tdd, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

How can I enable migrations in a testing project?

`PM> Enable-Migrations`

> Could not load assembly 'CreditoImobiliarioBB.EntityFramework.Test'. (If you are using Code First Migrations inside Visual Studio this can happen if the startUp project for your solution does not reference the project that contains your migrations. You can either change the startUp project for your solution or use the -StartUpProjectName parameter.)

Comment: In principle, there is no problem using EF migrations in any kind of project. Have you investigated the hints given in the error message?  
What I would challenge although is the usefulness of using migrations in a test project. Typically, migrations will be applied to a project containing your data classes. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your Startup Project (in Solution Explorer) and your Default Project (in Package Manager Console) are set correctly?

The Startup Project setting should be familiar to you if you've developed any web applications before. e.g. if you have an ASP.NET MVC web project, this should be selected as the startup project (shown in bold) in the Solution Explorer.

As you probably know, this ensures that running the application will load this web project in the browser. In addition to that, you should also know that this is where Migrations will try to locate the web.config file with the proper DB connection string.

The Default Project setting (different from the aforementioned Startup Project) setting is set in a dropdown within the Package Manager Console, where you run commands such as Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration and Update-Database.

I would recommend enabling your migrations in a data layer project. But if you want to use your Test project, make sure you select the name of the Test project in the Default Project dropdown of your Package Manager Console.

Hope this helps!

[image]